# PHP filter_var URL Bug

Tags: cloudcontrol

My Cloudcontrol project is currently suffering from this PHP-Bug: [filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) acting weird in PHP 5.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266794/filter-varurl-filter-validate-url-acting-weird-in-php-5-3-2)

Can you do anything about it? I worked some days ago so I guess you've updated the PHP Version.

My Project's name: mitfahrmonster

Thanks 
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

the luigi stack with PHP 5.3.2 didn't change within the last days. We will have a look at this bug.

As a general suggestion, if it is possible use the pinky stack (PHP 5.4.14). This will be the default stack within the next days. phpinfo: http://pinky.phpinfo.cloudcontrolled.com/

You can switch between the two stack with `cctrlapp app_name/dep_name deploy --stack {luigi,pinky}`

Best regards
Tobias Wilken